# vector insert method's return iterator position

Tags: vector, insert, iterator, return

I made some code to study vector, and somehow couldn't understand with insert's return value.

https://ideone.com/KckxbU

I thought when myvector got inserted, return iterator should be

```
  200 100 100 100
(here)
```

and after this code

```
myvector.insert(it, 2, 300);
```

myvector should be like

```
200 300 300 100 100 100
```

but vector contain

```
300 300 200 100 100 100
```

WHY?

Comment: You're inserting 300 twice at the beginning of the vector.

Comment: I don't think insert() return beginning of this vector.. that's my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation clearly states that the new elements are inserted at the position pointed to by the input `iterator` parameter. Elements are NOT inserted to the position immediately after the supplied `iterator`, which is what you seem to be expecting.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/

> position
>
> Position in the vector where the new elements are inserted.
>   iterator is a member type, defined as a random access iterator type
>   that points to elements.

Your code is inserting an integer of value 200 starting at the first position in the `vector`. All other elements are moved up by one position.

```
it = myvector.begin();
it = myvector.insert(it, 200);
```

So

```
100 100 100
|||
```

becomes

```
200 100 100 100
|||
```

The return `iterator` from `insert` is

> An iterator that points to the first of the newly inserted elements.

So `it` still points to the first position of the `vector`.

Then you add two integers of value 300

```
myvector.insert(it, 2, 300);
```

So the vector contains

```
300 300 200 100 100 100
|||
```

and `it` is set to the position of the first of the newly inserted elements which is still the first element of the vector.